# Clojure compiler messages in IntelliJ IDEA / La Clojure

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, la-clojure

Versions:

- IDEA: 12.0.4
- LaClojure: 0.5.228

---

I'm developing a mixed Clojure/Java project, with a Clojure main method calling Java and other Clojure code. This project worked in Eclipse. Upon trying to move the project to IntelliJ IDEA, I'm failing with a mysterious error message.

Of my 4 Clojure namespaces, 3 can be individually compiled with `Ctrl-Shift-F9`. So can my 3 Java files. But the main Clojure namespace yields:

```
! Error: Clojure Compiler:
```

Same thing happens with `Rebuild project`, `Make module` or `Make project`.

If there's an error lurking in my 33 line source that compiling in Eclipse didn't reveal, this error message is surely too scant to reveal it.

Does anyone know how to get the LaClojure-spawned compiler process to give more information?

Comment: Could this have something to do with the version of Clojure that is used by IntelliJ to compile your code ?

Comment: It certainly could, and that's a useful hint, thanks! I wonder how I'd go about fixing or even ascertaining that, but I'll give it a try later today. Still, having seen the verbosity of error messages straight from the horse's mouth, I wonder what the plugin did with the *original* messages and if there's some way I could retrieve them.

Comment: @Laurent Petit: The clojure.jar file in the La Clojure plugin directory is version 1.4.0, the latest greatest. This trail seems to have dead-ended, sorry! ;)

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a project which causes this error? If yes, please create an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard in Clojure project with that project attached.

Comment: Do you have Settings | Compiler | Use external build on?

Comment: @PeterGromov: Well I'll be buggered! Yes, exBld was on, and turning it off got me clean compiles.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: Thanks for the update. It's a bug, actually, it's supposed to work with external build. Is there any chance you could provide a sample project so that we could fix this?

Comment: @PeterGromov: Done. IDEA-103253. I'll of course be happy to help with any questions.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but since the Clojure plugins are improving and moving so fast, you should really consider upgrading IntelliJ to 14.1 and use the excellent Cursive Clojure plugin, which is the successor to La Clojure. It really has improved a lot in the last year.

Comment: are you able to build your project with command line, how those wired together, like mvn / lein ? that's the item to check aside changing IDE / picking differrent menu item